# Setting Access dates to various weekdays of the month

Tags: sql, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I have done a lot of research over the internet for something to help me with what I am trying to do, but haven't been able to come up with anything that helps my situation.

I'm new to using MS Access (using 2013 version) and I am working with a database through my SharePoint 2013 site. What I have is a SharePoint site that keeps track of lots of events through multiple lists. Essentially what I am trying to do is create a list template in SharePoint that I can just upload to the site instead of re-creating the list from scratch every month. With this list I have 1800 events per month and am trying to set the "Date" fields to the first, second, third, etc. Monday of the month, I am trying to do this for Tuesday through Friday also, so that way I don't have to manually set 1800 dates.

I figured this would be possible through MS Access rather than through SharePoint itself. At first I thought I would be able to set the default value to what I need each date field to be, but from my understanding this won't work, so I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to accomplish this in SQL. Now keep in mind that I have never used SQL before so I really don't know what I'm doing with it.

So in case that I didn't explain what I'm trying to do well, I'm trying to set date fields in Access to the 3rd Wednesday of the month, the second Thursday of the month, etc.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be some work to translate to pure SQL as the count of a weekday in a month will be either 4 or 5, but here is a generic function using VBA that does exactly this:

```
' Calculates the date of the occurrence of Weekday in the month of DateInMonth.
'
' If Occurrence is 0 or negative, the first occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
' If Occurrence is 5 or larger, the last occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
'
' If Weekday is invalid or not specified, the weekday of DateInMonth is used.
'
' 2016-06-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateWeekdayInMonth( _
    ByVal DateInMonth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal Occurrence As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal Weekday As VbDayOfWeek = -1) _
    As Date

    Const DaysInWeek    As Integer = 7

    Dim Offset          As Integer
    Dim Month           As Integer
    Dim Year            As Integer
    Dim ResultDate      As Date

    ' Validate Weekday.
    Select Case Weekday
        Case _
            vbMonday, _
            vbTuesday, _
            vbWednesday, _
            vbThursday, _
            vbFriday, _
            vbSaturday, _
            vbSunday
        Case Else
            ' Zero, none or invalid value for VbDayOfWeek.
            Weekday = VBA.Weekday(DateInMonth)
    End Select

    ' Validate Occurence.
    If Occurrence <= 0 Then
        Occurrence = 1
    ElseIf Occurrence > 5 Then
        Occurrence = 5
    End If

    ' Start date.
    Month = VBA.Month(DateInMonth)
    Year = VBA.Year(DateInMonth)
    ResultDate = DateSerial(Year, Month, 1)

    ' Find offset of Weekday from first day of month.
    Offset = DaysInWeek * (Occurrence - 1) + (Weekday - VBA.Weekday(ResultDate) + DaysInWeek) Mod DaysInWeek
    ' Calculate result date.
    ResultDate = DateAdd("d", Offset, ResultDate)

    If Occurrence = 5 Then
        ' The latest occurrency of Weekday is requested.
        ' Check if there really is a fifth occurrence of Weekday in this month.
        If VBA.Month(ResultDate) <> Month Then
            ' There are only four occurrencies of Weekday in this month.
            ' Return the fourth as the latest.
            ResultDate = DateAdd("d", -DaysInWeek, ResultDate)
        End If
    End If

    DateWeekdayInMonth = ResultDate

End Function
```

Comment: Would this code be able to go into the Visual Basic Macro on Access? Or would I need to format it for SQL?

Comment: It is VBA code. Copy-paste into a new module, compile and save. And you can use the function in a query. However, I don't know if your SharePoint environment would block this somehow.

Comment: I apologize for the delay, I've been out of my work center for about a week now. So I went ahead and tried to use the VBA code in a module and I saved it just fine, the only thing is, it does not seem to run through the code. Now I'm not too familiar with coding and coding software but I did see a "Run Sub/User Form" option in the editor and when I click on it has me create a new function. Is there a different way to go about running this code?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow. If you have no idea how to use a function in Access, do look up a beginners guide to save yourself a lot of trial an error.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `WEEKDAY` function.

For example you can get the next Sunday for any given date with the following:

```
=[date] - WEEKDAY([date]) + 7
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, if not please let me know and we can figure out something.

Comment: Maybe I am just doing this wrong, but I get the following error when working with that function "Fields of type Memo, Binary and Lookup cannot be used in a validation rule for Web tables."

Comment: What data type is your date in access and where are you putting the formula?

Comment: I am putting the formula into the default value of the field and using the MM/DD/YYYY format if that helps.

Comment: I see, this is suppose to go into a query as a new field.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I can see where this can be used now but Gustav's code works better for what I am doing. Again thanks for your help.